# I am not able to start hive in terminal and way taking too much time and not starting as show below

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

Hive error it took lot of time to start but hive shell is not started yet

I am not able to start a hive shell:

[image]

in terminal and way taking too much time and not starting as show below.

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive
2016-10-26 10:29:26,261 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GS2H.png)

Comment: Happens to me when you have duplicate terminals open or hive is busy. Just wait for sometime and try again. Works for me.

Comment: What's your vm and your host characteristics? hive-CLI is marked as deprecated anyway, you should try to use beeline to run HQL queries on your terminal. I'm not saying it will solve anything, but you may have any further messages to keep on investigating...

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens if there is no possibility to create a container for your hive process.

This can be caused by all kinds of things, like running hive queries or pig/other mapreduce jobs taking up all capacity.

Answer (score 0):

try to use beeline

!connect jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default